# How to create an enumeration or where should I store it?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have been using ExtJS and I find myself doing a lot of checking using "magic" strings. I would like to use some sort of enumeration i.e

Colors.Red, Colors.White

etc

Does Extjs support this, I am using version 4.2.

Also if I need to create a new class or something then where would the correct place for this be ?

I currently have

```
  /app
   controller
   store
   models
   views
    etc
```

These don't seem to be the correct location as these are specifically for controllers, views, models, stores ..

Where is the advisable place to create things that don't fit into the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This can be done differently, and it's just to give you some inspiration.*

What I have done in my app is creating a folder `enums` in my `app folder`. In this folder I put all my enums which I want to use in my app. Be aware that I use a `alternateClassName` and `uppercase` to make them more enum-like.

Just an enum:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.enums.Orientation', {
    alternateClassName: ['ORIENTATION'],

    statics: {
        PORTRAITPRIMARY: 'portrait-primary', // The orientation is in the primary portrait mode.
        PORTRAITSECONDARY: 'portrait-secondary', // The orientation is in the secondary portrait mode.
        LANDSCAPEPRIMARY: 'landscape-primary', // The orientation is in the primary landscape mode.
        LANDSCAPESECONDARY: 'landscape-secondary', // The orientation is in the secondary landscape mode.
        PORTRAIT: 'portrait', // The orientation is either portrait-primary or portrait-secondary.
        LANDSCAPE: 'landscape' // The orientation is either landscape-primary or landscape-secondary.
    }
});
```

I can use it like this:

```
MyApp.util.CordovaPlugins.lockOrientation(ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPE);
```

Where `lockOrientation` looks like this:

```
/**
 * Lock the viewport in a certain orientation and disallow rotation using the cordova screen orientation plugin
 * See [github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation)
 * for more details.
 *
 * Usage:
 * MyApp.util.CordovaPlugins.lockOrientation(ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPE);
 *
 * Possible orientations:
 * ORIENTATION.PORTRAITPRIMARY
 * ORIENTATION.PORTRAITSECONDARY
 * ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPEPRIMARY
 * ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPESECONDARY
 * ORIENTATION.PORTRAIT
 * ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPE
 *
 * @param {Enum} orientation Value of type MyApp.enums.Orientation to orientate the view in the given orientation.
 */
lockOrientation: function(orientation) {
    if (ORIENTATION.hasOwnProperty(orientation.toUpperCase())) {
        screen.lockOrientation(orientation);
    }
    else {
        Ext.Logger.error('The given orientation is not prohibited.');
    }
}
```

Another enum:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.enums.PositionError', {
    alternateClassName: ['POSITIONERROR'],

    statics: {
        PERMISSION_DENIED: 1,
        POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2,
        TIMEOUT: 3
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
getGpsErrorTitleByErrorCode: function(errorCode) {
    var title;

    switch (errorCode) {
        case POSITIONERROR.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            title = 'PERMISSION_DENIED';
            break;
        case POSITIONERROR.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            title = 'POSITION_UNAVAILABLE';
            break;
        case POSITIONERROR.TIMEOUT:
            title = 'TIMEOUT';
            break;
        default:
            title: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR';
            break;
    }

    return title;
}
```

I add the enums to my `uses` array in the class where I use the enum:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.CordovaPlugins', {
    uses: [
        'MyApp.enums.PositionError',
        'MyApp.enums.Orientation'
    ],

    ...
});
```

Or in the `requires` array of `app.js` to make them globally:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.enums.*'
    ],

    ...
});
```

Comment: Nice, inspiration received :-) ... Yes that get me thinking and started understanding my options! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is just a JavaScript framework, so anything you can do in JavaScript you can do in Ext.

In terms of folder structure it's purely personal preference with the exception of their conventions for stores, models etc as you've described.
I'd suggest using a structure which is generic enough to apply to several projects so that you can migrate the structure if needed, or move aspects across projects without needing to shoehorn them in.

In terms of things like `Colours.Red`, again you can do this via normal JS, so perhaps an object like this:

```
var Colours = {
    Black: "#000000",
    White: "#FFFFFF"
};
```

To do this in a more Ext'y way, you're be looking at something like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Util', {
   statics: {
      Colours: {
         Black: 1, 
         White: 2
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This wasn't particularly helpful. Yes I am aware of doing it the pure javascript way. I have found a way of using "requires" inside the application.js and "defining" a class, and marking this as a singleton.

Comment: The folder structure is a personal preference but I was hoping to get some input from what others are doing. That was all.

Comment: If you're aware of a way to create a singleton or a static'esque class to avoid magic strings for your colour example and you're looking for subjective advise as to where to store your utility classes, I'm not sure what answers would be helpful.